# Create a meeting with AWS Chime SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I have a free tier plan with AWS and I'm trying to get get started with creating meetings using AWS SDK.

```
private AWSCredentialsProvider getAwsCredentials() {
    final BasicAWSCredentials basicAwsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, accessKeySecret);
    return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAwsCredentials);
  }
```

```
  @Bean
  public AmazonChimeSDKMeetingsClient getChimeMeetingClient() {
    return (AmazonChimeSDKMeetingsClient) AmazonChimeSDKMeetingsClientBuilder
      .standard()
      .withCredentials(getAwsCredentials())
      .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2)
      .build();
  }
```

I tried to create a meeting with simple request like this

```
  public Object createMeeting() {
    var request = new CreateMeetingRequest();
    request.withMediaRegion("us-west-2");
    return meetingsClient.createMeeting(request);
  }
```

But I don't even understand because I'm getting a ThrottlingException that doesn't make enough sense to me. I've gone through the docs but not helpful as regard understanding the concept of quotas.

**References:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime-sdk/latest/APIReference/API_CreateMeeting.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/chime-sdk.html

Thank you all.[image]

Comment: Hi everyone, I figured it out.

The problem was that when I was creating ChimeMeetingSDK, the region I set i.e. EU_WEST_2 is not available as a Control Plane Region.

I changed it to EU_CENTRAL_1 and it worked.

I found the details on this URL https://region.status.chime.aws/